# Error: Expected a type in FBSDKConversionValueUpdating file while install react-native-fbsdk-next

Tags: react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk, fbsdksharekit, react-native-fbsdk-next

> [image]
> Mac mini M1, 2020
> Xcode 14.0
> react-native 0.73.2
> Can you help me! please

I tried many ways but couldn't solve it, There was a time when I tried deleting those two error codes and it was able to build, but when I came back everything was the same as before.

Comment: Can you expand the "Expected a type" in the left pane.

Answer (score 0):

[image: it's like this MichaelBahl]

Even when I create a new project then add the library I get the error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).